# How to execute RNN in python using real values as input data?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, embedding-lookup

I'm trying to run LSTM in python.
Does anyone know how to override the "tf.nn.embedding_lookup (embedding, input_data)" method?
I'm using float values ​​in my input variable "input_data" but using this method requires integers.
**What option do I have to enter with float data in RNN?**

I'm using the "tf.nn.dynamic_rnn" method to run the network. I've also tried the "legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder" method but it also did not work.

```
embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [config.vocab_size, config.hidden_size])
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_data)
outputs, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=self.initial_state)
#outputs, last_state = seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, initial_state, cell, loop_function=loop, scope='rnnlm')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where your code is failing, but if it's failing at `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, maybe you just need to specify the `dtype` parameter:

`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=self.initial_state, dtype=tf.float32)`

as discussed in the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

If your `input_data` are floating point, I'd reconsider your approach. Is your data categorical, like words in a language or names of people in the world? If yes, then I'd recommend converting it to be an unsigned integer like `uint32`, which is (a) more intuitive to most people and (b) compatible with `embedding_lookup`. If not, then you probably don't want an embedding -- embeddings are (as far as i know..) only for categorical data. If you just want to reduce the dimensionality of your data, then I'd consider some other dimensionality reduction scheme like PCA, or maybe just a wide first layer of your net with a narrow output.